# Subset data with dates from lookup table in SAS

Tags: join, sas, dst, proc-sql

I have a dataset that I need to subset for dates that fall within daylight savings time and dates that are not within daylight savings time to perform different adjustments on each group of data. The lookup table, DST_HOUR_SHIFT contains dates from 2007-2020 (example below) and the main data table contains hourly meter data with a value for each hour from 2007-2020 (example below). Joins seem to be my Achilles heel and I do not know the most efficient way to separate the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DST_HOUR_SHIFT

DST_BEG      DST_END
03/11/2007   11/04/2007
03/09/2008   11/02/2008
03/08/2009   11/01/2009 

INITIAL_SYSTEM_LOAD
SHORT_DATE  HOUR   VALUE
01/01/2007   0     1225.00
01/01/2007   1     1170.00
01/01/2007   2     1124.00
01/01/2007   3     1101.00
```

Comment: Instead, I would recommend creating a user defined format that will code a date to DST or not. Does this need to get down to the hourly level? Formats, work off start/end so your first data set is almost set up perfectly for a CNTLIN data set.

Comment: @Reeza This doesn't need to get to the hourly level per se, the "hour" value is hour beginning and I am shifting to hour end and then need to adjust for the missing hour on the DST_BEG date. The wrinkle in this is that hour zero needs to become HE 24 of the previous day and the way our reports are set up that would mean I would need 2 formats one subset data to shift the zero hour (DST_BEG would need to be date of DST change +1 for this format) and separate format that subsets on the actual date of DST_BEG to adjust for the loss of the hour. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Why not just expand the interval dataset to include the periods you have left out and add in a field to indicate which type of interval this observation is?

Comment: You could either add hours into your format, and format it as an actual datetime, but since you've chosen to separate them you need to deal with them separately.